# How to scale layout proportionally to screen's physical size?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Need the whole layout width to fit exactly the same within the portrait physical width from the screen in any device, so that it doesn't matter the DPI, the screen size, the pixel portrait width, nor the width-height relation.

All I have managed to do right now is to override the font size from the user's Android configuration, by adding the next code to MainActivity.cs:

```
public override Resources Resources
{
    get
    {
        Configuration config = base.Resources.Configuration;
        if (config == null)
        {
            config = new Configuration();
        }
        config.FontScale = 1f;
        return CreateConfigurationContext(config).Resources;
    }
}
```

That made a great improvement, but still see plenty of difference between different devices, those devices may have longer or shorter screens, greater or smaller DPI, and different sizes. For example device Pixel 2 from emulator, which has 1080x1920 resolution and 420 dpi, the layout fits perfectly (I made it that way), but when I try in physical device Redmi 9 1080x2340 resolution and 395 dpi (about 3 mm bigger portrait width), the layout becomes a little bigger, and elements don't fit in.

How to make the layout width to scale proportionally to the physical size, so that it can always fit within the width from portrait mode no matter the device?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-display?tabs=android

Comment: If your project is Xamarin.Android,at first, you can get the phone's size before you design the UI or create different xml for different size screen. In addition, use the wrap_content instead of specific dp. Furthermore, you can also use the ConstraintLayout which can make the view in the UI show acorrding to the scale of screen's width. If your project is Xamarin.Forms, you should get the scale of the device first by the Essential, and then set the width and height of the view.

Comment: You can try to use the weight to set the width and height of the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using percentage or ratio dimension attributes of ConstraintLayout.

ConstraintLayout : [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout?hl=id#percent-dimension)